# PHP & MYSQL: Update not working with Foreach Loop

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli

My foreach loop doesn't work with the update statement in mysql. don't know what i'm doing wrong. here is my php snippet.

```
        foreach ($request['playlist_information'] as $playlist) {
        $playlistResult = "UPDATE video_playlists SET channel_id='".$playlist['channel_id']."', playlist_id='".$playlist['id']."', playlist_title='".$playlist['title']."', playlist_status='".$playlist['status']."', playlist_description='".$playlist['description']."', playlist_created='".$playlist['date_created']."'";
        $mysqli->query($playlistResult);
        var_dump($playlist['title']);
    }
```

and my request, coming from my javascript is like this:

```
        var param = {
    "channel_id": channelId,
    "video_id": videoId,
    "views": $scope.stats[0]['views'],
    "likes": $scope.stats[0]['likes'],
    "dislikes": $scope.stats[0]['dislikes'],
    "favorites": $scope.stats[0]['favorites'],
    "comments": $scope.stats[0]['comments'],
    "duration": $scope.stats[0]['duration'],
    "dimension": $scope.stats[0]['dimension'],
    "definition": $scope.stats[0]['definition'],
    "caption": $scope.stats[0]['caption'],
    "licensed_content": licensedContent,
    "upload_status": $scope.stats[0]['uploadStatus'],
    "privacy_status": $scope.stats[0]['privacyStatus'],
    "license": $scope.stats[0]['license'],
    "embeddable": embeddable,
    "public_stats_viewable": publicStatsViewable,
    "video_title": $scope.meta[0]['title'],
    "video_status": $scope.stats[0]['privacyStatus'],
    "video_description": $scope.meta[0]['description'],
    "video_tags": $scope.meta[0]['tags'],
    "playlist_information": {}
}



for (var i = 0; i < $scope.playlists.length; i++) {

    param["playlist_information"][i] = {
                    "channel_id": channelId,
                    "id": $scope.playlists[i]['id'],
                    "title": $scope.playlists[i]['title'],
                    "description": $scope.playlists[i]['description'],
                    "status": $scope.playlists[i]['status'],
                    "date_created": $scope.playlists[i]['datePublished']
    }

};
```

INSERT works fine and i can update fine without the foreach loop at the php part. i can't seem to pinpoint the problem. any help is appreciated. thank you!

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` in the php file to see what the post structure looks like..

Comment: What is the error, use some debugging and let us know the exact problem

Comment: print_r($_POST) shows and empty array. btw i'm using angularjs and creating a youtube api app.

Comment: @Noor, there is no error. when i var_dump the request before and after the php transfer, the variables change but it doesnt seem to reflect in the database

Comment: `Echo` query and run in MySQL directly.

Comment: What about your `where` condition?

Comment: @noor ok let me try, just a sec.

Comment: @user876345 don't need a where clause, it's a loop, it's just going to reinsert everything again

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with quotes in your query:

$playlistResult = "UPDATE video_playlists SET channel_id=**'".$playlist['channel_id']."'**, playlist_id='".$playlist['id']."', playlist_title='".$playlist['title']."', playlist_status='".$playlist['status']."', playlist_description='".$playlist['description']."', playlist_created='".$playlist['date_created']."'";

You might get syntax error:
Check bold text: '".$playlist['channel_id']."'

```
  $playlistResult = "UPDATE video_playlists SET channel_id=\'".$playlist['channel_id']."\', playlist_id=\'".$playlist['id']."\', playlist_title=\'".$playlist['title']."\', playlist_status=\'".$playlist['status']."\', playlist_description=\'".$playlist['description']."\', playlist_created=\'".$playlist['date_created']."\'";
```

I hope this helps and check your update condition as well if necessary.

Comment: yes it does say that there is a syntax error when i run it directly in the database,

Comment: **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$playlistResult = &quot;UPDATE video_playlists SET `channel_id`='&quot;.$playlist['channel' at line 1** i don't understand, the other update with this kind of syntax works

Answer (score 0):

first of all please recheck the code , it should be $_REQUEST[] not $request

```
 foreach ($_REQUEST['playlist_information'] as $playlist) {}
```